# What does "breathing of the lighter elements" mean?

Tags: meaning, literature, phrase-meaning

I'm reading *Yelizaveta Bam* of Daniil Kharms (tr. Neil Cornwell) and stumbled upon the following dialogue:

> **Ivan I.:** But who then lights the lamp?
>   **Pyotr N.**: No one, it burns by itself.
>   **Ivan I.**:But that surely cannot be!
>   **Pyotr N.**: Empty, stupid words!
>   There is an infinite movement,
>   the breathing of the lighter elements,
>   planetary motion, the earth's rotation,
>   the crazed alternation of day and night,
>   the combination of remote nature,
>   the anger and strength of remote nature,
>   anger and strength of untamed beasts
>   and the laws of light and wave.

(I emulated the formatting used in the book)

What does "the breathing of the lighter elements" mean here (or in general)? Since it is supposed to be an "infinite movement" I cannot relate it to the breathing of a living thing.

Comment: I'm afraid this is off-topic here. The phrase in question appears to be a fairly literal translation, and while it may have an idiomatic meaning in the original language, it does not in English. Moreover, the general tenor of the passage points towards expressionistic rather than discursive meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the phrase does not refer to a living creature, but rather to one or two of the four elements (fire, air, water and earth), and "lighter elements" may accordingly be both air and fire, but perhaps most likely air, i.e. wind. Hopefully, this makes sense if you look at the line following the one you are asking about; "the planetary motion, the earth's rotation".

Comment: Yah, it's an odd mixture of mediaeval, Newtonian and modern cosmologies.

Comment: @Hege Ibsen, very good explanation. I couldn't realize the relation to the four elements. But the use of word "breathe" still somewhat puzzles me. Is "breathing" the way those light elements be/exist?